# How to center v-btn on v-card and put it on cards edge?

Tags: css, layout, vuetify.js

I want to center button relatively to `v-card` element and then put it on its bottom edge.

By now I have two partial solutions that can do these things, but separately.

Following style puts my `v-btn` on `v-card` edge properly:

```
.middle {
   position: absolute;
}
```

On edge:

[image]

And following style centers it in v-card:

```
.middle {
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
}
```

Centered:

[image]

However when combined button is not centered anymore. How can I combine these two effects with CSS?

Below my `v-card` I have *vuetify* timeline element and just want to make nice button for timeline elements addition on the cross of its origin and title :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `:style="{left: '50%', transform:'translateX(-50%)'}"` to the `<v-btn>`

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!